# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String. I dont find the error

Tags: java

I'm getting this error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty
> String".

I don't know what I doing wrong. I've put all the right types of variables. What can I do to correct it?

```
package com.mycompany.quadradomagico.exercicio2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuadradoMagico {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Variável de linha e coluna
        int l, c;
        
        //Recebendo os valores
        System.out.printf("Informe o número de linhas:\n");
        l = read.nextInt();
        
        System.out.printf("Informe o número de colunas:\n");
        c = read.nextInt();

        //Verificando se é um quadrado
        if (l != c) {
            System.out.printf("Não é um quadrado.");
        }
        else {
            //Matriz do quadrado
            double q[][] = new double[l][c];
            
            //Recebendo os valores da matriz
            for(int i=0; i<l; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<c; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Insira um valor para a posição ("+(i+1)+","+(j+1)+"):");
                    q[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
                }
            }
            
            //Exibindo os valores da matriz
            for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
                    System.out.print(q[i][j]+ "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in which line did you get this exception ?

Comment: in the 30......

Comment: at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
 at com.mycompany.quadradomagico.exercicio2.QuadradoMagico.main(QuadradoMagico.java:30)

Comment: take a look at my answer

Comment: The error is that you passed an empty string to `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: You are reading a **full line** with `nextLine` and then attempting to stuff this into a single `double`, although it contains **multiple** doubles. You have to just read one of them, by using `next()` or just `nextDouble` directly. Or `nextLine()` but then `split` the line first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this `q[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());` line by this one `q[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(read.next());`

Result :

```
25.0  55.0  45.0  6.0  5.0  
5.0  55.0  5.0  4.0  7.0  
7.0  7.0  45.0  45.0  5.0  
65.0  45.0  65.0  56.0  645.0  
456.0  45.0  45.0  564.0  546.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use [`Scanner#nextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) instead.

```
q[i][j] = read.nextDouble();
```